# MPAndroidchart, how to stop grid lines from flickering?

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidchart library to plot a line graph whith the data obtained from the volume of the microphone. Everything seems to work ok but the grid lines. The problem is that they are continuously flickering (dissapearing, changing the space between them...), which is not really nice.

I was wondering if there is a way so they are not repainted all the time.

Thanks and kind regards.

Comment: GridLine is  on Axis.If Axis is changed, it will change.